# single-line std::get std::index_sequence?

Tags: c++, stdtuple

I have a `std::tuple`, and I want to unwrap the contents using `std::index_sequence` in order to call a variadic function template

Consider the following example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename... Ts>
void foo(const std::string& s, Ts... ts)
{
    std::cout << "foo called with " << s << " and " << sizeof...(Ts) << " ts\n";
}

template<typename Tuple, std::size_t... Ixs>
void call_foo(const std::string& s, Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Ixs...>)
{
    foo(s, std::get<Ixs>(t)...);
}

template<typename... Ts>
struct Bar
{
    Bar(Ts... ts) : t(ts...)
    { }

    void do_it()
    {
        call_foo("hi", t, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<decltype(t)>::value>{});
    }

    std::tuple<Ts...> t;
};

template<typename... Ts> Bar<Ts...> make_bar(Ts... ts) { return Bar<Ts...>(ts...); }

int main ()
{
    auto bar = make_bar(1, 'a', 2.3);
    bar.do_it();
}
```

Note that I have to call through `call_foo` with my `index_sequence` in order to *"unwrap"* the `index_sequence` for calling `std::get...`

Is it possible to forego the intermediate `call_foo` function, and call `foo` directly?

That is, unwrap the tuple directly at the call-site?

Comment: If you have access to C++17: `std::apply(foo, t);`

Comment: @MilesBudnek I've updated the question which adds an additional parameter to `foo` (other than the tuple elements) - `apply` would no longer work directly would it? I'd have to capture the other parameter in a lambda first, and then pass that to `apply`?

Comment: That or make a tuple that contains all the arguments.  Perhaps [`std::tuple_cat`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat) is relevant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to or can't use `std::apply`, I can suggest a few alternatives.

The snippets below are based on the previous revision of your question that didn't have the `class Bar` in it. The same solutions work for the new revision as well.

**(1)** You could replace `call_foo` with a C++20 lambda with an explicit template parameter list:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template<typename... Ts>
void foo(const std::string& s, Ts... ts)
{
    std::cout << "foo called with " << s << " and " << sizeof...(Ts) << " ts\n";
}

template<typename... Ts>
void bar(Ts... ts)
{
    const std::string s = "hello world";
    const auto t = std::make_tuple(ts...);

    [&]<std::size_t ...I>(std::index_sequence<I...>)
    {
        foo(s, std::get<I>(t)...);
    }
    (std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(t)>>{});
}

int main()
{
    bar(1, 'a', 2.3);
}
```

<kbd>[Try it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26bc2cce86367d59)</kbd>

Unfortunately, GCC 8 currently seems to be the only major compiler that supports those.

---

**(2)** If your compiler doesn't have the new fancy lambdas, or you don't want to write the `index_sequence` boilerplate every time you need to expand the tuple, I suggest following:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <std::size_t ...I, typename F> void with_sequence_impl(F &&func, std::index_sequence<I...>)
{
    func(std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{}...);
}

template <std::size_t N, typename F> void with_sequence(F &&func)
{
    with_sequence_impl(std::forward<F>(func), std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}

template<typename... Ts>
void foo(const std::string& s, Ts... ts)
{
    std::cout << "foo called with " << s << " and " << sizeof...(Ts) << " ts\n";
}

template<typename... Ts>
void bar(Ts... ts)
{
    const std::string s = "hello world";
    const auto t = std::make_tuple(ts...);

    with_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<decltype(t)>>([&](auto ... i)
    {
        foo(s, std::get<i.value>(t)...);
    });
}

int main()
{
    bar(1, 'a', 2.3);
}
```

<kbd>[Try it live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d3ca31868346e564)</kbd>

Comment: Using `std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>{}` is a neat trick !